# How to view AdSense earnings per page

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

I have a blog which I have Adsense running. Right now I would like to be able to view earnings per page.

Basically to view how much earning each page/post generates. The idea is to be have more insight into the kind of contents: topic, length etc and how much earning they bring.

I can't seem to be able to view this via the Adsense dashboard nor via google analytics dashboard.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found it finally in google analytics.

Behavior -> Publisher -> Publisher Pages.

Here is a report on impressions, clicks etc and also earning per page.